# Pass Arraylst<Arraylist<String>> to MSSQL Stored procedure using JAVA?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, mssql-jdbc

Here I am trying to pass List to stored procedure but getting the following error:

> Operand type clash: nvarchar is incompatible with UserType

```
//Stored Procedure
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UserDetails]
(
                @OutId NVARCHAR(50) OUTPUT,
                @Type NVARCHAR(50) Type,
                ,@Preload UserType READONLY
)
AS
```

UserDefined datatype

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[UserType] AS TABLE(
                [Id] [int] NULL,
                [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
                [Company] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
                [PNumber] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
                [FClass] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
)
GO
```

JAVA Class

```
package Test;

import java.sql.Array;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Clob;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestPreload {

                public static void main(String[] args) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> PreloadUser=new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
                                ArrayList<String> Preload=new ArrayList<String>();

                                Preload.add("1");
                                Preload.add("Danny");
                                Preload.add("123");
                                Preload.add("123");
                                Preload.add("N/A");

                                PreloadUser.add(Preload);

                                ArrayList<String> Preload2=new ArrayList<String>();
                                Preload2.add("1");
                                Preload2.add("Sam");
                                Preload2.add("123");
                                Preload2.add("123");
                                Preload2.add("N/A");

                                PreloadUser.add(Preload2);

                                try {
                                                DriverManager
                                                                                .registerDriver(new com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver());
                                                Connection conn = DriverManager
                                                                                .getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://....");
                                                CallableStatement stmt = conn
                                                                                .prepareCall("{call UserDetails(?,?,?)}");
                                                stmt.setString(2, "Test");
                                                stmt.setString(3, PreloadUser.toString());
                                                //stmt.setObject(3, PreloadUser.toString());

                                                stmt.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
                                                stmt.execute();
                                                System.out.println("OUTPUT : " + stmt.getString(1));
                                                                                                } catch (SQLException e) {
                                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                }

}
```

Stack Trace:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Operand type clash:
>   nvarchar is incompatible with UserType
>         at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:196)
>         at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1454)
>         at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:388)
>         at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:338)
>         at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:4026)
>         at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1416)
>         at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:185)
>         at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:160)
>         at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.execute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:320)
>         at carma.TestInsurence.main(TestPreload.java:71)

Comment: From the Stack Trace: *nvarchar is incompatible with InsuranceType*. What is `InsuranceType`? I can't see it in your code.

Comment: Actually that is UserType. Just updated.

Comment: Do not forget to put highlights. I have done it for you this time.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `{call UserDetails(?,?,?)}` but your stored procedure do not take any argument. You need to change your stored procedure as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_Students_INS_byPK
       @user_id                     INT                       , 
       @user_name                   NVARCHAR(50)      = NULL  , 
       @user_company                NVARCHAR(100)     = NULL  ,
       @user_pno                    NVARCHAR(100)     = NULL  ,
       @user_fclass                 NVARCHAR(100)     = NULL  ,
AS 
BEGIN 
     SET NOCOUNT ON 

     INSERT INTO dbo.Students
          ( 
            Id                            ,
            Name                          ,
            Company                       ,
            PNumber                       ,
            FClass                                  
          ) 
     VALUES 
          ( 
            @user_id                      ,
            @user_name                    ,
            @user_company                 ,
            @user_pno                     ,
            @user_fclass                                  
          ) 

END
```

Change your code as follows:

```
CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall("{call UserDetails(?,?,?,?,?)}");
stmt.setInt(1, 1);
stmt.setString(2, "Sam");
stmt.setString(3, "123");
stmt.setString(4, "123");
stmt.setString(5, "N/A");
stmt.execute();
```

Moreover, I don't understand why you are inserting the data in your table by calling the stored procedure. You can simple use the `PreparedStatement` to do so. Here is an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Connection conn = null;
   PreparedStatement stmt = null;
   try{
      DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver());
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://....");

      String sql = "INSERT INTO UserType("Id", "Name",
            "Company", "PNumber", "FClass") VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
      stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

      stmt.setInt(1, 1);
      stmt.setString(2, "Sam");
      stmt.setString(3, "123");
      stmt.setString(4, "123");
      stmt.setString(5, "N/A");

      stmt.executeUpdate();

      stmt.close();
      conn.close();
   }catch(Exception ex){
      ex.printStackTrace();
   }finally{
      try{
         if(numm != stmt)
            stmt.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
         se.printStackTrace();
      }
      try{
         if(null != conn)
            conn.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
         se.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

If you are using Spring Framework then you can utilize JdbcTemplate to do it easily. Here is an example:

```
SimpleJdbcInsert insertUser = new SimpleJdbcInsert(jdbcTemplate)
            .withTableName("UserType").usingColumns("Id", "Name",
            "Company", "PNumber", "FClass");

Map<String,Object> insertParameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();

/* Put Values */
insertParameters.put("Id", 1);
insertParameters.put("Name", "Sam");
insertParameters.put("Company", "123");
insertParameters.put("PNumber", "123");
insertParameters.put("FClass", "N/A");

Number generatedId = insertUser.execute(insertParameters);
```

Comment: Here I have to send two values to Stored procedure. Type and UserType. "UserType" is user defined and it has (Id, name, Company, Pnumber, Fclass)

Comment: How will it map your `UserType` Table in DB to your JAVA Object named `UserType`? It's no magic! Whay can't you just pass all the values of `UserType` like I demonstrated?

Comment: I need to pass UserType along with Type to Stored procedure not Directly update in UserType. UserType should go from StoredProcedure.

Comment: Can you please update your code by adding Type to stored procedure.

Comment: I'm no expert on SQLServer but I think this can't be done as there is no way to tell your Stored Proc the type of object it is receiving and how to convert/parse it.

Comment: @user2004685 I am using below code to insert record, which is working fine.

 Number number = simpleJdbcInsert.executeAndReturnKey(parameters);

but when I try to mock above snippet using mockito, it asks to mock datasource, connection etc... I did all but still getting below error, not sure how to mock/handle this:

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: The getGeneratedKeys feature is not supported by this database
 at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcInsert.executeInsertAndReturnKeyHolderInternal(AbstractJdbcInsert.java:443)

Comment: @amitkumar12788 It's hard to answer without looking at your code. Could you open a new question with your code snippets?